# Throw an exception when too many/few arguments are passed to main

Tags: java, exception, arguments, program-entry-point, args

I'm writing a dice rolling programme which has two parameters passed to the main, how many sides the dice has and the amount of times you want to throw it. I wanted to throw an exception if less than or more than two parameters are passed. How would I go about doing this?

I found [this](http://sswap.info/docs/Impl/Java-API/info/sswap/ontologies/exec/api/TooManyArgumentsException.html).
But I'm not really sure how to use it? Surely I must somehow specify the amount of arguments that are expected before that exception can be thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class Dice {
  public static void main(String... args) {

    // First, ensure there are 2 args
    if (args.length != 2) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exactly 2 parameters required !");
    }

    int firstArgInt;
    int secondArgInt;

    // Verify all args are integers
    try {
      firstArg = Integer.parseIng(args[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nbfe) {
      // 2 possible solutions : throw an exception, or assign a default value
      // - throw new IllegalArgumentException("First arg must be an integer");
      // - firstArg = 42;
    }
    try {
      secondArg = Integer.parseIng(args[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nbfe) {
      // Same as above
    }

    // Etc.

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what would I do however if I know wanted to check if the arguments were numbers? I would like to throw a different exception to be caught and dealt with however if my catch block catches IllegalArgumentException it won't know how to deal with because its the same type of exception?

Comment: I edited my answer to add the args type conversion. If an argument is not an int, you may want to assign it a default value instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: I tried adding another exception in the same way to the first one you created and it started throwing the following error: cannot find symbol 
throw new IncorrectInputException
           ^

I've included my code below

try
   {
    noOfFaces = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     if (noOfFaces < 2)
     {
      throw new IncorrectInputException();
     }
   }
   catch (IncorrectInputException lessThan2)
   {
    System.out.println("You must pass an integer greater than 2");
    System.exit(1);
   }

Comment: First, the parseInt() method throws a NumberFormatException is its argument does not represent a number, so you really should catch that exception first. Then, and only then, you can test if your number is less than two and take whatever action is appropriate, like throwing an exception. I see you use an `IncorrectInputException`, is that a custom exception you coded ? I would recommend sticking to the standart `IllegalArgumentException` that I used in my sample code above.